# I'm getting error :Minikube failed to start

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube

I have Minikube installed in a virtual machine.
When I run it using the minikube start --vm-driver=none command, it functions perfectly.

As a result of running minikube status, I got:

running kubelet on host: starting apiserver: halted kubectl Pointing to minikube-vm is correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to follow these below steps to resolve your issue** :

- Go to C:UsersYour User>/.kube/ and delete the config file before restarting minikube.
- Update Minikube to the most recent version, which is right now.
- Utilizing minikube delete and new, recreate your minikube cluster.
- Minikube update context is eager.

> ```
> minikube stop
> minikube delete
> minikube start
> ```

The restart was crucial . It won't start if you issue these commands without restarting it first.

**For further use In Minikube [Troubleshooting](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/), it is thoroughly explained. The commands listed below**

```
$ minikube logs
$ minikube start --alsologtostderr -v=2
$ kubectl config view
```

Comment: Helpful  to resolve above issue but now I 'm getting different error

Comment: What is the error you are getting